# Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm creating facebook like social media app using nodejs and ejs. I'm getting error " Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined". But I get this error on profile.ejs and not on newsfeed.ejs. profile.ejs render photo if there's photo in the post but if I post a post with text only,this "Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined" error occur.

app.js

```
app.get("/newsfeed", function(req, res){  

if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    Post.find({}, function(err, foundItem){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            const loggedUser = req.user;
            res.render("newsfeed", {posts: foundItem, loggedUser: loggedUser, foundUser: "undefined"});
        }
    }).sort({date: -1});
} else {
    res.redirect("/login");
}

});

app.get("/profile/:userProfile", function (req, res) {
    const userId = req.params.userProfile;
    const loggedUser = req.user
    if(req.isAuthenticated){
        User.findById(userId, function(err, foundUser){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("profile", {foundUser: foundUser, loggedUser:loggedUser});             
            }
        }).sort({date: -1});
    }
})
```

newsfeed.ejs

```
<% posts.forEach( function(post) { %>
<div class="post">

<!-- Post contents -->

<a href="/profile/<%= post.user %>" class="username"><%= post.name %></a>
<p class="date"><%= post.date %></p>
<p class="content"><%= post.content %></p>
<% if(post.img != "undefined") { %>
<div class="mediaFiles">
    <div class="imageOverlay"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
    <img src="data:image/<%=post.img.contentType%>;base64,
        <%=post.img.data%>" class="image" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
</div>
<% } %>
<hr>
<% }); %>
```

profile.ejs

```
<% foundUser.post.forEach( function(post) { %>

<div class="post">
<!-- Post contents -->
<a href="/profile/<%= post.user %>" class="username"><%= post.name %></a>
<p class="date"><%= post.date %></p>
<p class="content"><%= post.content %></p>
<% if(post.img != "undefined" || post.img != null || post.img != "") { %>
<div class="mediaFiles">
    <div class="imageOverlay"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
    <img src="data:image/<%=post.img.contentType%>;base64,
        <%=post.img.data%>" class="image" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
</div>
<% } else { %>
    <div class="imageOverlay"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
    <img src="#" class="image" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: post.img != "undefined" should be typeof post.img!="undefined" or post.image != undefined, Like you are checking for null without inverted commas, same way you should do for undefined. Try this and let us know.

Comment: @TusharShahi it works. I didn't notice that I've spent like 2days to figure it out. Ty so much.